# Resize Virtualbox Ubuntu VM storage not taking effect

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I followed these instructions to resize my VirtualBox Ubuntu VM on Mac:
http://osxdaily.com/2015/04/07/how-to-resize-a-virtualbox-vdi-or-vhd-file-on-mac-os-x/

This is after the change:

```
*****-M-D2KA:$ VBoxManage showhdinfo ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/P4_Runtime/P4_Runtime.vdi 
UUID:           ce0ccd77-f265-46cd-9679-e25e64f1c992
Parent UUID:    base
State:          locked read
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /Users/*****/VirtualBox VMs/P4_Runtime/P4_Runtime.vdi
Storage format: VDI
Format variant: dynamic default
Capacity:       25000 MBytes
Size on disk:   9967 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled
In use by VMs:  P4_Runtime (UUID: 5ea52b11-997f-45d8-b7d6-effa37a3b649) [Snapshot 1 (UUID: 409c1035-2134-4532-a931-a29018d33dc6)]
Child UUIDs:    540ae750-5307-44ef-a313-95134ae353b7
                165fe99e-490d-4dd9-9602-00e3aaa8f82c
```

But for some reason, it does not seem to take effect:
This is the "df -k" output in the VM, and I get "No space left on device" error:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda        10253588  9713020          0 100% /
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I missed. I used gparted to resize the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the VHD doesn't change the size of the partition `/dev/sda`. You can run `lsblk` inside the guest to see the additional space. To get the extra space that is available in the guest OS, you may

1. Use something like gparted as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/102748). Instructions to do that on VHD can be found [here](https://technology.amis.nl/2017/01/30/ubuntu-vm-virtualbox-increase-size-disk-make-smaller-exports-distribution/). Note that this might not be easiest, but you may be forced to if you plan to not move some of your mount points (Example if you're not ready to move `/home/` to a new partition).
2. Or, create a new partition, again instructions on how to do is present [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/102748). I would prefer this option over the first.